# VS 2013 SDK: How to develop an extension accesible through the editor's contextmenu?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm using **Visual Studio 2013**.

The project wizard of a `Visual Studio Package` project gives these three options:

[image]

However, what I pretend to do is create a very simple extension (which modifies the selected text) and it should be accesible through a command from the contextmenu of the text-editor, not a menu command neither a tool window and neither a custom editor (...I think).

Firstly, what is the project that I should select for my needs? (I'm using a menu command).

Secondly, what are the necessary steps to modify the behavior of the extension to add it only in the contextmenu of the text editor?.

Comment: Your guess is correct. None of these are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void CreateContextMenu()
{
    // Get a reference to the context menu of code windows.
    CommandBars commandBars = (CommandBars)applicationObject.CommandBars;
    CommandBar codeWindowCommandBar = commandBars["Code Window"];

    // Add a popup command bar.
    CommandBarControl myCommandBarControl = codeWindowCommandBar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlPopup,
        System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing);

    CommandBarPopup myPopup = (CommandBarPopup)myCommandBarControl;

    // Change its caption
    myPopup.Caption = "My popup";

    // Add controls to the popup command bar
    CommandBarButton myButton = (CommandBarButton)myPopup.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, 1, true);
    myButton.Caption = "Click Me";
    myButton.Click += myButton_Click;
}

void myButton_Click(CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
{
    MessageBox.Show("What's up?");
}
```

Comment: please, could you specify what is `applicationObject`?, I don't have any member with that name (at least in an VB.Net project), I need to reference a VisualStudio SDK assembly or...?. thanks again!

Comment: @ElektroStudios That would be the `DTE2` object.

Comment: Sorry but I'm in the same point, I don't know what kind of object I should cast to `DT2`

Comment: `DTE2 applicationObject = (DTE2)GetService(typeof(DTE));`

Comment: Aany idea of how to set an icon for the command and sub-command? :P I wonder exists a place where explains all things like these that you explained me (not MSDN).

Comment: Yes. Use `myButton.Picture`.

Comment: VS automation is a dark territory :)

Comment: I seen that property but is exposed only for the "Click me" sub-command object not for the main command object, and really no idea about how to create an stdPicture. thanks anyways!

Comment: Yes. They don't have icons. In fact, if you look carefully at all command bars (those controls that can be expanded) none of them have icons.

Comment: most of the commands in the default VS contextmenu has icons, and also the expanded commands too like for example the "Breakpoint -> Insert Breakpoint" command in the contextmenu of the code editor.

Comment: @ElektroStudios The "Insert Breakpoint" command is not expandable. It's a button.

Comment: @ElektroStudios Icons are only supported on non-expandable menu items.

Comment: hmm.... to understand us, "Breakpoint" is the expandable command, and "Insert breakpoint" is the comand-button.

Comment: Oh, ok, now I understand what you mean, sorry. its true I don't see any expandable menu with an icon, even of 3rd party extensions I have.

Comment: Yes. Breakpoint is a `CommandBarPopup` and Insert breakpoint is a `CommandBarButton`.

Comment: It's just not supported.