# VS 2013 SDK: Indentation issues with selected text

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

### Scenario

With **Visual Studio SDk 2013**, I'm trying to develop a simple extension that intends to modify the selected text to enclose it for specific XML documentation tags.

---

### Problem

The problem I have is when replacing the selected text, it only works with very especific conditions that I would like to avoid/improve.

To expose a real comparison, notice the perfection of the way that Visual Studio manages the indentation on the selected lines when commenting uncommenting the selected lines with **Ctrl + K + C** and **Ctrl + K + U** hotkeys, no matter where the selection index starts or ends because the entire (and non-empty) selected lines will be commented and preserving the indentation level:

[image]

That is the challenge I have with my own, this is the weird results I have with my extension, it only works properly if I fully select the lines including the whitespaces at the left, if not, i get undesired results:

[image]

---

### Question

In **VB.Net**, or else **C#**, how can I improve the logic of my code to fix the imperfections of the comparison above?.

The imperfections are basically that my extension cannot properly handle the starting blankspaces of the selected lines like VisualStudio does to perform a right text-replacing, so I get unexpected results as I mentioned.

---

### Code

This is the relevant code that I'm using:

```
Const XmlCommentCharsVB As String = "'''"
Const XmlCommentCharsCS As String = "///"

Private Sub ModifySelectedText()

    Dim viewhost As IWpfTextViewHost = Me.GetCurrentViewHost()

    Dim textView As IWpfTextView = viewhost.TextView

    Dim selectionSpan As VirtualSnapshotSpan = textView.Selection.StreamSelectionSpan

    Dim selectedText As String = selectionSpan.SnapshotSpan.GetText

    Dim language As String = textView.TextDataModel.ContentType.DisplayName

    Dim xmlCommentChars As String = ""

    Dim marginLength As Integer =
        (From c As Char In selectedText.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First
         Take While Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)
        ).Count

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedText) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder

    Select Case language.ToUpper

        Case "BASIC"
            xmlCommentChars = XmlCommentCharsVB

        Case "CSHARP"
            xmlCommentChars = XmlCommentCharsCS

        Case Else ' VC++
            ' Not implemented.

    End Select

    With sb
        .AppendLine(String.Format("{0} <example> This is a code example.", xmlCommentChars))
        .AppendLine(String.Format("{0} <code>", xmlCommentChars))

        For Each line As String In selectedText.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0} {1}", xmlCommentChars, line.Remove(0, marginLength)))
        Next

        .AppendLine(String.Format("{0} </code>", xmlCommentChars))
        .AppendLine(String.Format("{0} </example>", xmlCommentChars))
    End With

    selectionSpan.Snapshot.TextBuffer.Replace(selectionSpan.SnapshotSpan, sb.ToString)

End Sub
```

---

### Research

VisualStudio SDK does not have any of easy, really it's a nightmare to find any code-example on the MSDN reference, or non-guru explanations that let understand the end-user the purpose of "X" member of the SDK, so I should imagine by my own what could do "X" member and put it in practice to see what happens... I'm totally blind about how to solve this.

Anyways, I put my eyes on the `TrackingMode` property of the `ITrackingSpan` interface, it explains something about the edges of the editor... but I tested it and seems it does not refers to the blankspace edges.

Also, I think that a major problem coould be that I'm getting the selected text in this way:

```
viewhost.TextView.Selection.StreamSelectionSpan.SnapshotSpan.GetText
```

I'm just getting an String, but the SDK provides an `ITextSnapshot` interface with a collection of strings in the `Lines` property, however, I've tried to retrieve the propert `Snapshot` for the selected text but I always get all the text of the current editor view...

Comment: Have you checked out tools like GhostDoc? And you do know that if you type three *///* for Csharp or three *'*'s for VB that XML documentation is added automatically and you can use this to make help documentation. Sorry its unrelated but what program/tool did you use to make the gif images?

Comment: Yes I have GhostDoc (Pro version), but I'm not sure if it can be configured to xml-documment pieces of code in the way that I'm trying, I've tried to analyze the GhostDoc templates before trying to make my own extension. Of course I know the beneffits of XML documentation to make API references compiled as Chm file for example, that's why I would like to do this to add code examples with  those tags in the help files. The Gif recorder I use is: http://screentogif.codeplex.com/ . Thanks for comment

Comment: Very nicely and clearly written question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Get the selection object.
var viewHost = GetCurrentViewHost();
ITextSelection selection = viewHost.TextView.Selection;

// Get the start and end points of the selection.
VirtualSnapshotPoint start = selection.Start;
VirtualSnapshotPoint end = selection.End;

// Get the lines that contain the start and end points.
IWpfTextViewLine startLine =
    viewHost.TextView.GetTextViewLineContainingBufferPosition(start.Position);
IWpfTextViewLine endLine =
    viewHost.TextView.GetTextViewLineContainingBufferPosition(end.Position);

// Get the start and end points of the lines.
SnapshotPoint startLinePoint = startLine.Start;
SnapshotPoint endLinePoint = endLine.End;

// Create a SnapshotSpan for all text to be replaced.
SnapshotSpan span = new SnapshotSpan(startLinePoint, endLinePoint);

// Compute margin.
string[] lines = span.GetText().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
int margin = lines.Select(line =>
{
    int count = 0;
    while (char.IsWhiteSpace(line[count++])) ;
    return --count;
}).Min();

// Construct the replacement string.
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}{1} {2}", new string(' ', margin), "///", line.Remove(0, margin)));
}

// Perform the replacement.
span.Snapshot.TextBuffer.Replace(span, sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Can you give an explanation as to where and what this fix is?

Comment: @JeremyThompson I believe this answers the question. This piece of code goes inside the `ModifySelectedText` function from the question.

Comment: @Hadi Brais Just amazing, thanks so much!. Only to mention that the code you've published does not handle empty lines, it will throw an error because count value is negative, but i solved that issue adding a `Where(Function(line As String) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))` in the linq query. I just need to perform a deep testing of the code before giving the bounty reward, but it seems to work perfectly in the same way as VisualStudio does... thanks!.

Comment: PS: Maybe you could help in this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160915/vs-2013-sdk-how-to-develop-an-extension-accesible-through-the-editors-contextm

Comment: @ElektroStudios Yes I think I can and I understand exactly what you want to do.